# Microsoft Lifechat LX-3000 headset issue

Tags: headset

I bought the [Microsoft Lifechat LX-3000 headset](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/digitalcommunication/productdetails.aspx?pid=006) just yesterday, but as soon as I plugged it in I found out that the sound quality is so bad. Its full of glitches and fuzz. However the speakers of my laptop work fine.

Someone told me that it was a Windows Vista problem but the Microsoft webpage says that there is no such thing ([Microsoft reference](http://goo.gl/9qp5)).

Any help please?

Comment: Seems like this would be more appropriate on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Nick - not really, this is not really an independent electronic device, rather a computer peripheral. As such, it's on topic on Super User.

Comment: @Gnoupi OK, I see.